# div fires click event even after using off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div which has a click event.

```
<div id="e_tooth_pk1" class="e_tooth_pk1" title="Tooth 1">Tooth 1</div>
```

JS here:

```
$("#e_tooth_pk1").off("click");
$("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function() {
    alert("hiii");
});
```

I tried using `off` to stop click event but it fires it.I think am missing something.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/somnath_k/EaA5A/2/)

Comment: change the order, that will work. First bind .click, then .off

Comment: Why not use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/)?

Comment: What is your expected behaviour? Your code/jsFiddle doesn't make any sense here

Comment: @A.Wolff His scenario is different. look at the conversation went in my post.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy But where does OP explain what he is looking for?

Comment: @A.Wolff div fires click event even after using off the question heading explains what am looking for

Comment: @SomnathKharat AFTER means after, not before. You were unbinding none bound handler here, and then AFTER that, binding a click event. Your logic was quite hard to follow, if any...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the event to the off state, you are binding it again. that is the problem here.

Try,

```
$("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function() {
    alert("hiii");
});

$("#e_tooth_pk1").off("click");
```

But i wonder why do you need this to occur. I think you are looking for the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) function.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EaA5A/3/)

Comment: that was a same example created .my scenerio is different one.so no need on one method

Comment: Then i'm wondering why OP bound event in first place. Again, OP should have tell us the behaviour he was expecting

Answer (score 1):

You might want like this:

```
$("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function() {
    alert("hiii");
   $(this).off('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the click event again after turning it off. Try putting the off after the click.

```
$("#e_tooth_pk1").click(function() {
    alert("hiii");
});

$("#e_tooth_pk1").off("click");
```

Fiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/EaA5A/5/

Answer (score 0):

### Solved

Vanilla js [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n8mUK/)

```
var elem = document.getElementById('e_tooth_pk1');
elem.addEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);

function eventHandler(){
    alert("hiii");
    this.removeEventListener('click', eventHandler, false);
}
```

Comment: For code consistency, it's still better to use jQuery when obviously rest of code is using it. BTW, this code would need to handle case for older browser not supporting addEventListener/removeEventListener methods

Comment: @A.Wolff, I agree with you completely.